# UITextField pops up too high when using TPKeyboardAvoiding class

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitextfield

I'm using the [`TPKeyboardAvodingScrollView` class](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding) to make sure the keyboard never pops over the `UITextField`. However there is some strange bug on the iPhone, when I click on the `UITextField` the textfield goes up but too high:

[image]

On the GitHub link the Notes say this:

> Notes
>
> These classes currently adjust the contentInset parameter to
>   avoid content moving beneath the keyboard. This is done, as opposed to
>   adjusting the frame, in order to work around an iOS bug that results
>   in a jerky animation where the view jumps upwards, before settling
>   down. In order to facilitate this workaround, the contentSize is
>   maintained to be at least same size as the view's frame.

Maybe it has something to do with this, I'm just not sure how I can fix this problem.

I already tried changing this line:

```
[self setContentOffset:CGPointMake(self.contentOffset.x, 
                                   [self idealOffsetForView:firstResponder withSpace:[self keyboardRect].origin.y - self.bounds.origin.y])
```

with (added +100):

```
[self setContentOffset:CGPointMake(self.contentOffset.x, 
                                   [self idealOffsetForView:firstResponder withSpace:[self keyboardRect].origin.y - self.bounds.origin.y+100])
```

but this isn't a good way to do it since this won't work on the iPad.

Comment: where is the issue...working fine ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same problem recently. For me, solution was to modify -(CGFloat)idealOffsetForView:(UIView *)view withSpace:(CGFloat)space method. Here is how it looks in my project:

```
-(CGFloat)idealOffsetForView:(UIView *)view withSpace:(CGFloat)space {

// Convert the rect to get the view's distance from the top of the scrollView.
CGRect rect = [view convertRect:view.bounds toView:self];

// Set starting offset to that point
CGFloat offset = rect.origin.y;


if ( view.bounds.size.height < space ) {
    // Center vertically if there's room
    offset -= floor((space-view.bounds.size.height)/2.0);
}
if ( offset + space > self.contentSize.height ) {
    // Clamp to content size
    offset = self.contentSize.height - space;
}

if (offset < 0) offset = 0;

return offset;
}
```

The change was to remove first path from conditional block: if ( self.contentSize.height - offset < space ) and leave just "else" path.

Comment: Didn't test it for iPad, but on both iPhone screens it works good.

Comment: Is there any way you can get the UITextField even closer to the keyboard?